# How can I create jagged text in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I am trying to make the letters of my text look like they are "electrified" with jagged edges.  How would I do that??  I've tried making my text an object and then doing the "envelope" thing but that didn't seem to offer any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Would help a bit if you mentioned what version of Illustrator you are using. Otherwise the effect might not exist.

In CS5 or CS6 I might try:

`Effect > Distort & Transform > Roughen or Zig Zag`.

Cool thing about Effects is they are none destructive so no need to outline text or expand paths.

Check your Appearance panel to disable or make changes on the fly.

Comment: I wasn't aware Adobe made  version 6.2 of Illustrator. There's 6, then 7, no 6.2.